# NotifyPropertyChanged not working when updating model

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp

Note: I'm using PostSharps NotifyPropertyChanged attribute.

I see the textbox update in the view when I set the property in the ctor, however if I wire up a click event to a button and set the same property to something else the textbox isn't updated. What am I doing wrong?

```
public partial class TestForm : Window
{
    private MyViewModel _vm;
    public TestForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = _vm;
        _vm.MyText = "Test 1"; //Updates in UI
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _vm.MyText = "Test 2"; //No update in UI
    }
}

[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string MyText { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Forms.Activate.TestForm"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Width="300" Height="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=MyText}" 
             Margin="0,123" Width="100" />
    <Button Content="Button" Margin="29,154,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Run the compiled assembly through a decompiler and make sure that PostSharp has weaved in the code as expected.

Comment: It didn't add anything to the class marked with the attribute :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your model

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText
    public string MyText { get {return _myText;} set { if (value != _myText) _myText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); } }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

I have not thrown it through a compiler, but it looks right ;-)

Comment: I'm using PostSharp, so all of this boilerplate code goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think having a `NotifyPropertyChanged` attribute works.  I've never seen it anyway.

Try something more like this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myText;
    public string MyText
    {
        get
        {
            return _myText;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_myText != value)
            {
                _myText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyText");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged` has a small problem. you didn't prevent `PropertyChanged` from becoming `null` in some multithreading conditions. @Dustin 's code does.

Answer (score 0):

Provide an UpdateSourceTrigger of your textbox binding to PropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is nothing wrong with the code. After a reinstall of PostSharp it started to work.